# Shape of ground truth in multiclass image segmentation with pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I'm working on 128 x 128 x 3 cell images and want to segment them into 5 classes including backgrounds. I first made target images to be 128 x 128 and values are in {0,1,2,3,4}. But I found I have to make my target ground truth as 5-channel image, and all the values are 0 or 1: if a pixel has 1 in the nth channel, then it should be classified to nth class.

But when I run my model into a Unet model which I forked from GitHub, I found there's an error while calculating cross-entropy loss.

I initially set up the number of channels in the input to be 3 and the number of classes in the output to be 5. And batch size = 2

Here is my codes:

```
for i, (x, y) in batch_iter:
    input, target = x.to(self.device), y.to(self.device)  # send to device (GPU or CPU)
    self.optimizer.zero_grad()  # zerograd the parameters
    out = self.model(input)  # one forward pass
    loss = self.criterion(out, target)  # calculate loss
    loss_value = loss.item()
    train_losses.append(loss_value)
    loss.backward()  # one backward pass
    self.optimizer.step()  # update the parameters

    batch_iter.set_description(f'Training: (loss {loss_value:.4f})')  # update progressbar

self.training_loss.append(np.mean(train_losses))
self.learning_rate.append(self.optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr'])

batch_iter.close()
```

And error message

```
RuntimeError: 1only batches of spatial targets supported (3D tensors) but got targets of size: : [2, 5, 128, 128]
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please add the hyperlink of the U-Net model

Comment: What is the shape expected by the model? There might be an `assert` line failing just before when this error is raised.

Comment: @Abhi25t Hi, here is the link to the model I used: https://github.com/milesial/Pytorch-UNet.git.

Comment: The expected output shape of the model is [2,5,128,128]. I couldn't find a corresponding assert statement

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using either `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` or `nn.functional.cross_entropy`

I also faced the same error.

CrossEntropyLoss is usually used for classification use cases.

If your targets are normalized tensors with values in `[0, 1]`, you could use `nn.BCELoss` or `nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits`. This worked in my case as we are using separate mask for each class - it becomes a binary cross entropy problem.